# Winsock receiving random letters trough recv()

Tags: c++, winsock

I am trying to make a Winsock Chat. I want to send packets which sit between 2 "tags". kind of like "^^^TAG^^^ *packet data* ^^^TAG^^^"

Problem is, the Client Apps I am using, including my own Client app I wrote either send the message wrong or my Server app is receiving the data wrong

Here is what I mean:

[Using Hercules TCP Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJfmD.png)

[Using my own Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kg1B.png)

I am aware why it is split, that's what my Tag idea is for, but if you read what I send and what I got you will see there's added and replaced letters. At a certain point I even got the words that I sent followed by "================================" then other random unicode characters, but I could not get it again to screenshot.

Due to the fact most of the TCP clients I got off of the internet didn't work, I assume the problem is with how I receive the packets rather than how I and the other programs are sending them

**My code:**

heres a rewritten simple version of my code

```
struct client_info
{
    SOCKET sock;
    const char* ip;
    int port;
};

struct server_info
{
    SOCKET sock;
    const char* ip;
    int port;
    std::vector<client_info> clients;
    int client_count;

    HANDLE connection_handler;
    HANDLE recv_handler;
};

struct param_info
{
    void* server_info_pointer;
};

class my_server
{
public:
    my_server(const char* ip, int port)
    {
        this->m_info.ip = ip;
        this->m_info.port = port;

        this->start();
        this->client_handler();
        this->recv_packet();
    }
    ~my_server(void)
    {

    }
private:
    server_info m_info;

    bool start(void)
    {
        WSADATA lpWsaData = decltype(lpWsaData){};

        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &lpWsaData);
        this->m_info.sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        sockaddr_in lpAddr = decltype(lpAddr){};
        lpAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        lpAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(this->m_info.ip);
        lpAddr.sin_port = htons(this->m_info.port);

        char chOption = 1;
        setsockopt(this->m_info.sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &chOption, sizeof(chOption));
        setsockopt(this->m_info.sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &chOption, sizeof(chOption));

        if (!bind(this->m_info.sock, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&lpAddr), sizeof(lpAddr)))
        {
            return true;
        }

        closesocket(this->m_info.sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    bool client_handler(void)
    {
        param_info pi = param_info{};
        pi.server_info_pointer = &this->m_info;

        if (this->m_info.connection_handler = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>
            (this->client_handler_internal), &pi, 0, nullptr))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    static void client_handler_internal(void* param)
    {
        auto pi = reinterpret_cast<param_info*>(param);

        if (!listen(reinterpret_cast<server_info*>(pi->server_info_pointer)->sock, SOMAXCONN))
        {
            client_info ci = client_info{};

            sockaddr_in lpAddr;
            int dAddrSize = sizeof(lpAddr);

            while (ci.sock = accept(reinterpret_cast<server_info*>(pi->server_info_pointer)->sock, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&lpAddr), &dAddrSize))
            {
                ci.ip = inet_ntoa(lpAddr.sin_addr);
                ci.port = htons(lpAddr.sin_port);

                printf("%s:%d joined!\n", ci.ip, ci.port);

                reinterpret_cast<server_info*>(pi->server_info_pointer)->clients.push_back(ci);

                memset(&ci, 0, sizeof(ci));
                Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        return;
    }

    auto __forceinline recv_packet(void) -> bool
    {
        param_info pi = param_info{};
        pi.server_info_pointer = &this->m_info;

        if (this->m_info.recv_handler = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>
            (this->recv_packet_internal), &pi, 0, nullptr))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    static void recv_packet_internal(void* param)
    {
        auto pi = reinterpret_cast<param_info*>(param);

        for (;;)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reinterpret_cast<server_info*>(pi->server_info_pointer)->clients.size(); ++i)
            {
                char * lpBuffer = new char[64];
                if (0 < recv(reinterpret_cast<server_info*>(pi->server_info_pointer)->clients.at(i).sock, lpBuffer, sizeof(lpBuffer), 0))
                {
                    std::string lpNewBuffer = lpBuffer;
                    printf("%s\n", lpNewBuffer.c_str());
                }

                memset(lpBuffer, 0, sizeof(lpBuffer));
            }

            Sleep(50);
        }

        return;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you verified that nothing else is communicating on that port? I haven't worked with winsock but I know that some higher level TCP libraries will create a "virtual port" which can mess up Windows' pidgeon holing.

Comment: You need to save how many bytes were read by `recv()` so you know many to use when assigning them to a string...

Comment: @jmkmay i have checked the ports and this one isnt being used

Comment: @Shawn i have just done what you said. used malloc to allocate 128 bytes, saved the return value from recv then reallocated. it was not my problem. if you look at my screenshot youll see random characters appear in the middle or the string of text or sometimes replace other characters

Comment: Your code just checks to see if `recv()` returned a value greater than 0, and if so, assigns an entire char array to a string, not just how many characters were read. If there aren't any 0 bytes in that buffer, bad stuff happens.

Comment: Plus it uses `sizeof` on a pointer, which is just going to return the size of the buffer, so it's only even attempting to read 4 or 8 bytes depending on if you're using a 32 or 64 bit system. And the memory you allocate for that pointer to point to is never freed so there's a memory leak...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (0 < recv(reinterpret_cast<server_info*>(pi->server_info_pointer)->clients.at(i).sock, lpBuffer, sizeof(lpBuffer), 0))
```

You ignore the return value of `recv`, so your code has no idea how many bytes it received. Also, see below for why `sizeof(lpBuffer)` is wrong here.

```
memset(lpBuffer, 0, sizeof(lpBuffer));
```

Since `lpBuffer` is a `char *`, this zeroes `sizeof(char *)` bytes, which is not right. Only use `sizeof` when you need the size of a *type*. Also, why are you zeroing a buffer you already used and will never use again?

```
std::string lpNewBuffer = lpBuffer;
```

You should have used the return value from `recv` here to know how many bytes `lpNewBuffer` should be.

Don't treat things as strings if they're not strings. Store the return value of `recv` so you know how many bytes you received.